# Force JS change the URL'S when change page

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting

I'm using jquery to load an external portion (ex:  content ) of a file and animate the page when the user clicks a link. My problem is: I want to change the url when the user clicks a link. Something like http://www.gop.com.pt/#!youAreHere

You can see it [here](http://www.gop.com.pt) in action

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this, you can simply use JavaScript:

```
document.location.hash = '!youAreHere';
```